# What is fashion in the wizarding world?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, wizards

I am about to buy clothes to cosplay Pansy Parkinson- but... what were clothes like in the wizarding world? Parkinson is a blood supremacist so she wouldn't wear muggle clothes, and since so many wizards are pureblood, what do they wear? is it linked to a specific time?

Comment: From JKR, see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/RowlingWritings/comments/98k2kl/clothing/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/RowlingWritings/comments/aaw0tv/colours/).